# How to update an array of objects according another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays:

```
initial=[{code:"1",size: 0},{code:"2",size: 0},{code:"3",size: 0},{code:"4",size: 0}];
update=[{code:"1",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 120}];
```

I need to get new array like this:

**I want to group by code field and do the sum of size after grouping.**

```
new=[{code:"1",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 220},{code:"3",size: 0},{code:"4",size: 0}];
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this update? And what have you tried already?

Comment: need way more detail on what you're trying to accomplish. Array comparisons are tricky and very specific

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hash table for the objects with same code.

```js
var initial = [{ code: "1", size: 0 }, { code: "2", size: 0 }, { code: "3", size: 0 }, { code: "4", size: 0 }],
    update = [{ code: "1", size: 100 }, { code: "2", size: 100 }, { code: "2", size: 120 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = initial.map(function (o) {
        return hash[o.code] = { code: o.code, size: 0 };
    });

update.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[o.code].size += o.size;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I saw in many answers posted by you that you used `Object.create` instead of `{}`. Can you tell me the advantage of `Object.create` over `{}` ? Thanks !

Comment: it prevents false results with keys like `toString`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
var o1 = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2, c: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()`, `.filter()` and `.reduce()` methods of `Array.prototype`

```js
let initial = [{code:"1",size: 0},{code:"2",size: 0},{code:"3",size: 0},{code:"4",size: 0}];
let update = [{code:"1",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 120}];

let res = initial.map(({code, size}, index) => 
            ({code, size: size 
             // get elements having same `"code"` property value from `update` array
             // add the result
             + update.filter(({code:c}) => code === c)
             .reduce((n, {size:s}) => n+= s, 0)})
          );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using an ES6 `Map` in a *functional programming* style:

```js
function addObjects(acc, add) {
    return Array.from(
        add.reduce((mp, {code, size}) => mp.set(code, mp.get(code) + size),
                new Map(acc.map(({code, size}) => [code, size]))),
        ([code, size]) => ({code, size})
    );
} 

const initial = [{ code: "1", size: 0 }, { code: "2", size: 0 }, { code: "3", size: 0 }, { code: "4", size: 0 }],
      update = [{ code: "1", size: 100 }, { code: "2", size: 100 }, { code: "2", size: 120 }];

const res = addObjects(initial, update);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#concat` to join your array and then use `array#reduce` to sum up the sizes inside an object and then get the values from that object.

```js
const initial=[{code:"1",size: 0},{code:"2",size: 0},{code:"3",size: 0},{code:"4",size: 0}],
      update=[{code:"1",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 100},{code:"2",size: 120}];

let result = initial
              .concat(update)
              .reduce((res, {code, size}) => {
                res[code] = {code, size : (res[code]|| {size:0}).size + size};
                return res;
              },Object.create(null));

let output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```